# Large Screen Capture on html page

Tags: c#, html, windows-live-writer

I have an html source on a string variable. I need to capture that html into a jpeg while making it A3 size. My ultimate goal is to print it in better quality.

I have achieved this using 'WindowsLive.Writer.Api' (function HtmlScreenCapture()), it works well in most of the cases.

Zooming is done as follows;

```
<html><body style=zoom:4></body></html>
```

But, when the server is too busy it tends to fail this process and this is a very expensive process.

Any better ideas achieving the same with the least amount of time, CPU and memory?